# Ticks not appearing with a stacked bar chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a stacked bar chart in matplotlib which is coming up fine except that I do not see the xticks in the plot.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(20, 10), subplot_kw=dict(frameon=True))

n = 6

i=0
for lineage, j in zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], axes.flatten()):
    x=list(map(lambda x: int(x.strip()[1:-1]), lineage_snp[lineage].value_counts().index))
    y=list(lineage_snp[lineage].value_counts().values/lin_counts[lineage])
    j.bar(x, y, label = lineage, alpha=1, width=100, color = colors[lineage])
    j.legend(loc = 'upper left')
    j.grid(True)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)
    i+=1
   
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

What am I missing here? If I keep grid on I can get the grid where the tick should be but I prefer the grid be off and only a tick appear at the label.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this, by setting xtick here, you want labels to be only on the x-axis of bottom subplot? If this is the case, by setting x and y with random values, I could not reproduce your problem.

Comment: What is `lineage_snp`?

Comment: Ideally I would want it to be on all plots, but just the bottom would be fine too.

Comment: `lineage_snp` is a pandas dataframe which contains the data I am plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it. I was using style `seaborn-whitegrid`, on changing to `seaborn-ticks` the ticks came fine.